# Forwarding or syncing SMS to another Android phone

Tags: sms, sync

I have two Android phones and I am looking for a way to foward SMS messages to another phone and let me answer with my first number. I don't have both phones with me all the time, but still want to be notified about new messages (and if possible even calls).

I need something more than a simple forwarder. Already tried apps like "SMS Forwarding" "SMS forwarder" etc. That wasn't it.

Comment: You didn't mention what Phone or OS (custom ROM, standard factory, or vanilla android) you are using, because the feature might already be included in your device. I'll make a new answer that might solve the problem if you're using a Samsung phone with standard factory ROM.

Comment: It would probably be easier to just use Google Voice. Then SMS sent to your GV number can be managed from any device where you have the app (or the Google Chrome extension, for your desktop).

Comment: Google Voice assumes that OP is located in the U.S. - because this service is available to users of a U.S. mobile number only. Have a look at the bottom of this FAQ: https://support.google.com/voice/answer/115061?hl=en

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I noticed an application on the Android store called "MySMS" that seems to sync between phone, tablet, and PC/Mac. Maybe this is the solution to your problem.

Downloadable from:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mysms.android.sms&hl=en

The same company also has a premium service for 2 phone syncing - which has the same features as above but specifically for sycning 2 phones together. Since the other app doesn't require a premium (paid) service, its worth trying to see if that does the job for free. If not, then it might be worth trying out their second app.

This is the premium version for 2 phones:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mysms.android.mirror&hl=en

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello again :) I've been using the premium version for 2 phones (mysms mirror) for the last few days now and it's perfect. The app syncs my texts and calls instantly. Exactly what I was looking for. Only the set up was a bit complicated, but once this is done, it's great.

Answer (score 1):

There is a guide posted on T-Mobile for people with Samsung phones that already include this feature to sync SMS messages between phones using the Microsoft Exchange server, Live or Hotmail account. I'll outline the steps here for archiving purposes.

**Link to guide:**
http://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-7313

**Android 4.1 and higher**

1. Open Email.
2. Press Menu.
3. Touch Settings.
4. Touch the Exchange email address.
5. Touch More (this many not be available in all devices).
6. Select (turn on) or clear (turn off) the check box for SMS Sync.

**Android 1.5 - 4.0**

1. From the device Settings menu, touch Accounts and sync.
2. Touch your Exchange email account.
3. Select (turn on) or clear (turn off) the check box for Sync SMS or Sync Text.

**Note:** For this feature to work, your Exchange server must support it.